# GStreamer: properly send EOS event on ctrl+c

Tags: python, gstreamer

I can successfully record video from videotestsrc via the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

When I run the command above and press ctrl+c, I get a playable `output.mp4` file.

I want to replicate this behavior via Python Gst bindings. However, I'm unable to correctly handle ctrl+c behavior

```
import gi
from time import sleep

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib  # noqa


def bus_call(bus, message, loop):
    t = message.type
    if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("EOS")
        loop.quit()
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        loop.quit()
    return True


def main():
    Gst.init(None)
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()

    pipeline = Gst.ElementFactory.make("pipeline", None)
    src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc", None)
    convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", None)
    encode = Gst.ElementFactory.make("x264enc")
    mux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("mp4mux")
    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", None)
    sink.set_property("location", "output.mp4")

    pipeline.add(src, convert, encode, mux, sink)
    src.link(convert)
    convert.link(encode)
    encode.link(mux)
    mux.link(sink)

    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message", bus_call, loop)

    ret = pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        return

    try:
        loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
    finally:
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        loop.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Whenever I run a program and press ctrl+c, I get not playable `output.mp4`. How should I properly handle ctrl+c event in my Python code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some time I've managed to handle this problem. I run `GLib.MainLoop` in a separate thread and wait until it finishes after ctrl+c event in Python code:

```
import gi
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib  # noqa


def bus_call(bus, message, loop):
    t = message.type
    if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        loop.quit()
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        loop.quit()
    return True


def main():
    Gst.init(None)
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    thread = Thread(target=loop.run)
    thread.start()

    pipeline = Gst.ElementFactory.make("pipeline", None)
    src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc", None)
    convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", None)
    encode = Gst.ElementFactory.make("x264enc")
    mux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("mp4mux")
    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", None)
    sink.set_property("location", "output.mp4")

    pipeline.add(src, convert, encode, mux, sink)
    src.link(convert)
    convert.link(encode)
    encode.link(mux)
    mux.link(sink)

    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message", bus_call, loop)

    ret = pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        return

    try:
        while loop.is_running():
            sleep(0.01)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("interrupted")
        pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        while loop.is_running():
            sleep(0.01)
    finally:
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        loop.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I'm wondering if it's a proper way to handle my issue in Python code.